# Want YARN to edits spark's property

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am running Spark on YARN. in `spark/conf/core-site.xml` there are  properties like

```xml
...
<property>
   <name>...</name>
   <value>...</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>my.target.keyA</name>
  <value>MY_TARGET_VALUE_AAA</value> 
</property>
...
```

Want to change `MY_TARGET_VALUE_AAA` to `MY_TARGET_VALUE_BBB` without editing any configs on Client Side but YARN itself edits it depending on some rules we've already deployed after spark submits the app to YARN.

So I rewrite yarn nodemanger code in `hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/nodemanager/DefaultContainerExecutor.java`

```java
@Override
  public int launchContainer(ContainerStartContext ctx) throws IOException, ConfigurationException {
    ....
    List<String> localDirs = ctx.getLocalDirs();
    List<String> logDirs = ctx.getLogDirs()
      
    Log.info("--------------- change start --------------------------------")
    Map<Path, List<String>> localizedResources = ctx.getLocalizedResources();
    Set<Path> paths = localizedResources.keySet();
    for (Path path : paths) {
        String pathName = path.toUri().getPath();
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(pathName) && pathName.contains("__spark_conf__.zip")) {
        File[] configFiles = new File(pathName).listFiles();
        for (File configFile:configFiles){
           if (configFile.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("__spark_hadoop_conf__.xml")){
                // backup the xml
               // add MY_TARGET_VALUE_BBB to the xml
           }
        }
    }
    Log.info("--------------- change end --------------------------------")
      
    FsPermission dirPerm = new FsPermission(APPDIR_PERM);
     .....
   }
```

then on NodeManager:

```bash
[yarn@test-nm]$ ll /data01/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/MY_USER/filecache/159/__spark_conf__.zip
total 612
drwx------ 2 yarn yarn   4096 Jan 13 17:15 __hadoop_conf__
-r-x------ 1 yarn yarn   2604 Jan 13 17:14 log4j.properties
-r-x------ 1 yarn yarn   8337 Jan 13 17:14 metrics.properties
-r-x------ 1 yarn yarn   4881 Jan 13 17:14 __spark_conf__.properties
-r-x------ 1 yarn yarn 298985 Jan 13 17:14 __spark_hadoop_conf___bak.xml # original xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 yarn yarn 297313 Jan 13 17:15 __spark_hadoop_conf__.xml   # new xml
```

but my newly added `MY_TARGET_VALUE_BBB` doesnt work.

Comment: What exactly is the use case here? What properties are you looking to change?

Comment: Hi OneCricketeer, we want to add some Alluxio properties when apps are submitted to YARN. I know the cause now: in client mode, all executors are launched with broadcast Hadoop configuration sent by driver, not the newly configurations on executors. change it to cluster mode then it works.